# jQuery: how to get the dimensions of a external image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, dimensions

Looking for a way to get the dimensions *(width and height)* of an external image. 
I have used `prop()` and `attr()`, but they don't return any values. Just an error.

**Example:**

```
<a href="pathtotheimage">some link</a>
```

Comment: Your only way is to load the image. (if you use JavaScript)

Comment: Ah make sense, cant get the dimensions if the image isn't loaded. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**jQuery**

```js
var path = 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/600x300/?montreal';
$("<img/>").attr('src', path).load(function() {
    console.log(this.width, this.height);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Vanilla Javascript**

```js
var path = 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/600x300/?montreal';
var img = new Image();
img.src = path;
img.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log(this.width, this.height);
});
```

Comment: The `.load` event won't fire if the image is pulled from the browser cache. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3877027/901048) for solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like none has provided a working vanilla js answer.

```
var img = document.createElement('img')
img.src = 'http://domain.com/img.png'
img.onload = function() {
    console.log( this.width )
    console.log( this.height )
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/VMfVZ/

Answer (score -1):

This isn't technically jQuery but I would go down the route of:

```
var image = new Image(), width, height;
image.src = 'http://whereyourimage.is/heresmyimage.jpg';
width = image.width;
height = image.height;
```

You can then access those values using `width` and `height`, for example `alert('My image is ' + width + ' pixels accross.');`

Comment: This cannot work because you are accessing the width at the same time you are setting the src so the browser cannot possibly give you the correct information.

Comment: Worked for me but I've just realised that image was cached! Fool! Will edit answer when I'm back at a computer